# How to use ogr2ogr for batch conversion?

Tags: ogr, esri-coverage-format, advanced-license-level

I have a thousand of arc coverage would like to covert to shapefile. How can I use the ogr2ogr to convert it in batch rather than convert it one by one? It takes a lot of time! Any idea?

Comment: Just loop over the files using a script (bash, python, whatever you've got). That doesn't really have anything specifically to do with GIS in general or OGR specifically.

Comment: `for /R %f in (*.E00) do ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" "%~dpnf" "%f"`

Comment: Right!! It works! for /R %f in (*.adf) do ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" "%~dpnf.shp" "%f"

Answer (score 0):

What BradHards said (in a comment, why not an answer? Sorry I'm new here).

Write a script, even a good-old DOS batch file would work. But since you are using ogr2ogr you likely have python installed. So make a list of the files to convert, and iterate through that list in a python script making the call to ogr2ogr in the loop for each file.

Comment: No answer because its off topic.